# getting commit messages with log between specific revision range GIT

Tags: git, logging, commit

I`m not familiar with Git and I have a problem with it.

In SVN, I can use `svn log HEAD:100` to get log messages between the HEAD revision and the 100th revision.

Is there something similar in Git so that I can get the log messages for a specific range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than one way to do this. Please read the manual page (7) for gitrevisions.

```
man 7 gitrevisions
```

For your example above you can use this command:

```
git log HEAD~100..HEAD
```

If you need all commits between two revisions you need between the two revisions three dots.

```
git log Rev1...Rev2
```

Comment: thanks for comment. For more general question assume that I have 2 revision number num1 and num2 . I dont know which one is the bigger. I want to get log messages between these two revision number. How could I do that ?

Comment: I`m so greatful . It gives me the all commits between two revision number right ? If I write git --git -dir=PATH Rev1...Rev2 it gives me the log messages of the path between two revision number right ? @silvio

Comment: not exactly. You have to write "git --git-dir=<repo/path>/.git log REV1...REV2" ... "--git-dir" is a option to the git command.

Comment: @silvio   could git log Rev1...Rev2 with more param get a diff commit log list with no-merges?

Comment: @butter: The Option `--no-merges` is useful for that.